# Query works in MySQL but returns no results when using Spring Data repository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Customer` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_system_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "system_id")
    )
    private List<System> systems;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Customer(UUID id,
                    String displayName
                    List<System> systems) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.systems = systems;
    }
}
```

and a `System` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system")
@Data
public class System {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    public System() {}

    public System(UUID id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

(the `@data` annotation is from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) and automatically generates getters and setters).

I also have a `CustomerRepository` (which is using a [property expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) to query based on the `id` property of `System`):

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer> {

    Page<Customer> findBySystems_id(UUID id, Pageable pageable);

}
```

**What I wish to happen, is that calling findBySystems_id returns all Customers which are mapped to a `System`** by using the `JoinTable` `customer_system_mapping`.  A `Customer` has a `System` if `customer_system_mapping` has an entry matching `[customer_id, system_id]`.

This is the SQL generated by JPA:

```
select
    customer0_.id as id1_0_,
    customer0_.name as name_5_0_
    from
        customer customer0_ 
    left outer join
        customer_system_mapping syst1_ 
            on customer0_.id=syst1_.customer_id 
    left outer join
        system syst2_ 
            on syst1_.system_id=syst2_.id 
    where
        syst2_.id = ? limit ?;
```

This is the log of the SQL binding:

```
binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [3023f335-5d28-4244-996b-286a5f5c3446]
```

**When I copy/paste the generated SQL code and bound parameter into MySQL, I get one result back (the correct behavior).  But when I call `findBySystems_id("3023f335-5d28-4244-996b-286a5f5c3446", pageable);`, I get no results back.**

Answer (score 0):

the first letter of the attribute should be upper case

```
 Page<Customer> findBySystems_Id(UUID id, Pageable pageable);
```